# error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type

Tags: matlab, octave

I am training my neural network on this digit recognition problem but when I run the optimizer function I get the following error:

```
    >error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type
    >error: called from
        fminunc at line 214 column 12
        optimization at line 3 column 18
```

For more clarification, given below is the code for:

1) Optimization function:

```
    >function 
    [theta_final,cost,accuracy,digit]=optimization(X,y,initial_theta,lambda)
    options=optimset('GradObj','on','MaxIter',20);
    [theta_final,cost]=fminunc(@(theta)CostCompute(X,y,theta,lambda),initial_theta,options);
```

2) Cost Computation

```
    >function[cost,gradient_vector]=CostCompute(X,y,theta,lambda)
    input_layer_size=400;
    hidden_layer_size=25;
    num_labels=size(unique(y));
    theta1=reshape(theta(1:(hidden_layer_size*(input_layer_size+1))),hidden_layer_size,input_layer_size+1);#10025, 97.4
    theta2=reshape(theta(1+(hidden_layer_size*(input_layer_size+1)):end),num_labels,hidden_layer_size+1);#260, 2.
    m=size(X,1);
    hidden_layer=sigmoid(theta1*X');
    hidden_layer=[ones(1,size(hidden_layer,2));hidden_layer];
    output_layer=sigmoid(theta2*hidden_layer); 
    output=[];
    for i=[1:m]
       temp=zeros(1,num_labels);
       temp(y(i))=1;
       output=[output;temp];
        endfor
        reg=sum(theta.*theta);
        cost=-(1/m)*sum(sum(output.*log(output_layer')+((1-output).*log(1-output_layer'))));#+reg*lambda/(2*m);
        [gradient_vector]=backprop(X,y,theta1,theta2,num_labels,m,lambda,output);
        endfunction
```

3) Backpropagation

```
    >function [gradient_vector]=backprop(X,y,theta1,theta2,num_labels,m,lambda,output)   
        temp_y=zeros(1,num_labels);
        hidden_layer=sigmoid(theta1*X');
        hidden_layer=[ones(1,size(hidden_layer,2));hidden_layer];
        output_layer=sigmoid(theta2*hidden_layer); 
         delta_output_layer=output_layer-output';
        gradient2=delta_output_layer*hidden_layer';#10x25 changes made in hidden_layer
        gradient2=gradient2*(1/m);
        delta2=(theta2')*delta_output_layer;
        delta2=delta2.*sigmoid_gradient(hidden_layer);
        delta2=delta2(2:end,:);
        gradient1=delta2*X;
        gradient1=gradient1*(1/m); 
        gradient_vector=[gradient1(:);gradient2(:)];
    end function
```

None of the matrices have a size which crosses the limitation of the memory or octave's index type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank You!

Comment: this error typically occurs either if you've got a really big matrix, _or_ (more likely to be the case), you have attempted to access / assign at an index that exceeds the maximum integer value allowable in your system  (which you can find out what that is using `intmax`). E.g. type `a(intmax+1) = 1` to see the error.

Comment: Ah... obfuscating your code by placing a `>` before each line, rendering your code un-executable... a BOLD choice...

Comment: @beaker Thanks for pointing that out. Edited!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I checked the intmax value and it cam out to be  '2147483647'. Additionally, the size of the input matrix is 5000x401.

Comment: If the matrices are within acceptable size, then the problem is the index. If the index is within acceptable limits, the problem is the matrix size. Without a working example to test there's not much else to say here.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I tried to compute the parameters using gradient descent and for loop and I am using the same cost function and back propagation code. It runs fine and doesn't show any error related to the matrix size. Is it possible that there is any problem with the execution of the fminunc()?